# Using GDCM via CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, gdcm

I downloaded source of GDCM 2.4.1 and used CMake 2.8.12.1 and Visual Studio 2010 to build the libraries. I want to use GDCM in my C++ project.
Unfortunately, it seems that after building the GDCM solution with VS, there are only the lib-files in the bin folder, but no typical "include" folder with the header files, what I usually expect. Thus, I can't integrate GDCM libaries in my own project (I tried to use FindPackage(GDCM) in my own CMakeproject, but header files can't be found).

I do not want to copy the header files manually or target the source directory of GDCM.
Does anybody know help?

Comment: Hm, this seems very unusal to me. I work a lot with multiple C++ libaries. Usually the build process generates a new folder "include" and puts all needed header files into it. Targeting the source folder is suboptimal, because you also target non-header files...Also this is not the way described in the official GDCM documentation. They recommend to use FindPackage(GDCM), which does not work for me because the header files are missing.

Comment: You are not supposed to have the build folder the same as the source folder. And with GDCM (and other similar libraries based on CMake) I generally do not build the INSTALL project instead build the ALL_BUILD target and when I build my own CMake based application I set GDCM_DIR to the root folder which I built GDCM in.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the problem has something to do with VTK, I also use the this library in my project. So I need to enable "GDCM_USE_VTK" in CMake of GDCM. That option leads to a compiler error when I try to build the "INSTALL" subproject in the GDCM solution:

CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:31 (FILE): file INSTALL cannot find "D:/Libs/VTK_5.6.0/BIN/bin/vtkCommon.dll".

I took a look in the VTK directory and found out that the path mentioned above does not exists. Instead the dll is located in:

D:\Libs\VTK_5.6.0\BIN\bin\Release\vtkCommon.dll or
D:\Libs\VTK_5.6.0\BIN\bin\Debug\vtkCommon.dll

That means GDCM solution does not know the dll is located in a special debug or release folder. If I disable "GDCM_USE_VTK" everything works fine and all files will be copied to the target folder. But I do need the VTK dll.
Any thoughts?

Michael

Comment: The install project is supposed to install to C:\Program Files\VTK unless you have changed the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and you have permission to install there. Although again I will caution using that since using it locks you into using only Debug or Release for all of your code (not both) if you use  BUILD_SHARED. The reason is you can not safely use the Debug heap and Release heap in a single application. This will lead to random crashes when allocating or deallocating memory.

Comment: Also why are you using a current version of GDCM with a several year old version of VTK?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I'm not using BUILD_SHARED, so I think I will not have problems. I will also try to specify the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX of VTK. The reason for old VTK and new GDCM is that the I currently update my program to newer libaries, starting with GDCM. Do you think it could be a problem using new GDCM and old VTK (temporarily)?

Comment: If it is asking for .dlls you have build shared enabled at least for VTK.

Comment: I have not tried that old of VTK with recent GDCM. Currently I do use GDCM-2.4.X with VTK-5.10.0 on both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 both in the x64 configuration. I develop in VS2010 but build the targets I distribute under VS2012. In all cases I disable BUILD_SHARED and use the procedure I described in my first post.

Comment: The procedure you described above does not work for me. It causes the error I mentioned in my first post. How do you link the GDCM libraries in your project's CMakeLists.txt? I did it the offical way. See "How do I use GDCM in my project ?" here: http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Common_questions

Comment: I use basically the same way + some setting of CMake variables. By default CMake will not find GDCM so I set GDCM_DIR. I used to manually do that on the first configure from cmake-gui but now I do this in a more scripted way with a batch file that sets environment variables + run cmake the first time from that environment and code in my applications CMake scripts to read the environment variables and set GDCM_DIR. Same with VTK_DIR, ITK_DIR, BOOST_ROOT DCMTK_DIR ...

Comment: Hmm. One thing that I do that the example on the sourceforge site does not is include(${GDCM_USE_FILE}) after finding GDCM

Comment: I tried include(${GDCM_USE_FILE}), this time I get some LNK2018 linker errors instead of the "missing header" errors. I checked some project properties, both GDCM project and my own project use same charcter set and same runtime library (MD). But I think we're coming closer the the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: E.G: 2>iisDicomReaderGDCM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall gdcm::Sorter::~Sorter(void)" (??1Sorter@gdcm@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall gdcm::IPPSorter::~IPPSorter(void)" (??1IPPSorter@gdcm@@UAE@XZ)

Comment: OR:   vtkgdcm.lib(vtkGDCMImageReader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum gdcm::PixelFormat::ScalarType __thiscall gdcm::PixelFormat::GetScalarType(void)const " (?GetScalarType@PixelFormat@gdcm@@QBE?AW4ScalarType@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall gdcm::PixelFormat::operator enum gdcm::PixelFormat::ScalarType(void)const " (??BPixelFormat@gdcm@@QBE?AW4ScalarType@01@XZ)

Comment: Both seem to point at missing gdcmMSFF. In an application that uses gdcm + vtk I am using the following in a target_link_libaraies(gdcmMSFF vtkgdcm vtkCommon)

Comment: Unfortunatelly there are still linker errors afterwards. For example:

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: unsigned int __thiscall gdcm::Directory::Explore(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?Explore@Directory@gdcm@@IAEIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall gdcm::Directory::Load(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,bool)" (?Load@Directory@gdcm@@QAEIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z)

Comment: Do you think I have to target ALL gdcm libraries?

Comment: gdcm::Directory is in gdcmCommon. I would add that one as well. You may have to include more gdcm libraries in your target_link_libraries.

Comment: Ok, I included all(!) libraries, now there's only one single final linker error left:

Comment: gdcmMSFF.lib(gdcmUIDGenerator.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__UuidCreate@4 referenced in function "protected: static bool __cdecl gdcm::UIDGenerator::GenerateUUID(unsigned char *)" (?GenerateUUID@UIDGenerator@gdcm@@KA_NPAE@Z)

Comment: Try adding Rpcrt4 to your target_link_libraries. I have that in 1 of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ever touches the same problem, here's the final solution. Build "**ALL_BUILD**" in the GDCM solution, then integrate GDCM libs in your CMakeLists.txt the following way:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(GDCM REQUIRED)
    IF(GDCM_FOUND)
        INCLUDE(${GDCM_USE_FILE})
        SET(GDCM_LIBRARIES 
            gdcmcharls
            gdcmCommon
            gdcmDICT
            gdcmDSED
            gdcmexpat
            gdcmgetopt
            gdcmIOD
            gdcmjpeg12
            gdcmjpeg16
            gdcmjpeg8
            gdcmMEXD
            gdcmMSFF
            gdcmopenjpeg
            gdcmzlib
            socketxx
            vtkgdcm
            Rpcrt4)
    ELSE(GDCM_FOUND)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find GDCM, did you set GDCM_DIR?")
    ENDIF(GDCM_FOUND)
```